# Need caching for PHP response for HTML files

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using HTML templates for my JS Frontend. When I request the HTML files with a "normal" URL like /public/templates/foo.html I get the HTML file and the next time I reload it gets cached. If I use a URL like /asset/templates?file=foo which will call a PHP script and returns a 'text/html' file (via readfile()) the cache is not working anymore. How to get the caching enabled again? I'm running nginx on my server.

That is what I get:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=900, pre-check=900
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 17:13:16 GMT
Expires: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 17:28:16 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:47:02 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But the Browser does not cache it.

Comment: Use varnish :) https://www.varnish-cache.org/

Comment: Mhh... It's like breaking a butterflie on a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. You may configure Cache-Control headers on your nginx for PHP files. Then they will become cacheable. Really bad idea as it will cache all PHPs regardless. Given dynamic nature of PHP it is something rarely needed and so is the reason why nginx does not cache PHP responses by default.
2. Add following in the beginning of your PHP code:

   header ("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=86400")
   header ("Pargma: cache")

It also appears specific to nginx: add the following line to your nginx configuration

```
proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires" "Pragma";
```

Otherwise nginx may replace these headers based on nginx config (ie ignore headers from PHP script).

Comment: I tried your second approach but it still not works. It's still sending 'Pragma: no-cache'

Comment: Pragma is HTTP/1.0 header, it is ignored by HTTP/1.1 clients if Cache-Control is present. But if you want to get Pragma set just do header("Pragma: cache");

Comment: Just to throw the iron in the fire: good read here https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: I added the response header in my question. Browser is still not caching it.

Comment: For starters browsers are not required to follow cache headers. They may just ignore them and request fresh copy anyway. In order to diagnose the reasons you should post all HTTP headers which are returned to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting a session with session_start(); This will trigger the pragma no-cache; header.

You can override this feature by changing the following in php.ini
    session.cache_limiter = public;

> session.cache_limiter specifies the cache control method used for session pages. It may be one of the following values: nocache, private, private_no_expire, or public. Defaults to nocache. See also the session_cache_limiter() documentation for information about what these values mean.

Taken from [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)